# Friendly profile URLs mix up with controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I allow users to use profile URLs like: **domain.com/AwesomeUser**

In my routes:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'user';
```

The issue that i have is that my controllers are inaccessible now, I can do something like:

```
$route['blog']    = 'blog';
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/$1';
$route['contact'] = 'contact';
```

For every controller and parameter i have, But it's just unreliable, I'd like something more efficient, I also have an array with the controller names that i'd like to exclude:

```
$reserved_names = array(
    'blog',
    'page',
    'contact'
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could have used `domain.com/profiles/AwesomeUser`

Comment: @Shiplu I know, But I don't prefer it.

Comment: Maybe the order plays a role? What if you put the user catch-all at then end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you

```
$reserved_names = array(
    'blog',
    'page',
    'contact'
);
foreach ($reserved_names as $name )
{
    $route[$name]    = $name;
    $route[$name.'/(:any)'] = $name.'/$1';
}

$route['(:any)'] = 'user';
```

Answer (score 1):

always put your wildcard last.
Routes work in the order that you define them, first one listed == first once called.